# Non-OP players cannot put blocks inside carpenter blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-mods

I am hosting an FTB Infinity Evolved Server on 1.7.10 version of Minecraft, with a Carpenter Mod Version 3.3.8.1. Non-OP players are unable to place blocks inside the wedge carpenter blocks, always resulting in the block being placed next to the carpenter block.

I have tested to verify whether the issue is with OP permissions and it appears that others were able to put blocks inside when I gave them OP permissions temporarily. However, when I de-opped myself, I was still able to place blocks inside, and some other users were also able to place blocks inside without the OP status.

How can I fix this to allow **all** non-OP players to interact with carpenter blocks?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your server's FTP files and find the config file for the Carpenter mod.

Usually it can be found in the following place: `config > CarpentersBlocks.cfg`

From there, find the below line and change the **true** value to **false**.

```
    # This will prevent players besides you and server operators from editing your objects.
    # Note: this does not protect objects against destruction (intentional), and may allow activation if appropriate. Also, the Carpenter's Safe is not affected by this.
    B:"Enable Ownership"=true
```

I tried the above on my server and it did wonders, everyone can now interact with carpenter blocks without issues.